# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined DataTable Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

I was working on the project and suddenly the DataTable started to remain `undefined` after initialization, well it doesn't initialize itself either for some reason.

This is how I'm using it:

```
declare var $;

export ClassName implements OnInit {
    dataTable: any;
    ngOnInit(){
        this.dataTable = $('#table').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          ordering: false,
          pageLength: 10,
          language: this.getLanguages(),
          searching: false,
          dom: 't',
          paging: true,
          columns: comp.getColumns(), // returns columns
          createdRow: ( row, data, dataIndex) => {
            /* code */
          }
        });
    // code doesn't come here
    }
}
```

The error on the console is;

```
core.js:5828 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at _fnCalculateColumnWidths (datatables.bundle.js:5601)
    at _fnInitialise (datatables.bundle.js:4715)
    at loadedInit (datatables.bundle.js:1294)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (datatables.bundle.js:1306)
    at Function.each (vendors.bundle.js:1290)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (vendors.bundle.js:1125)
    at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (datatables.bundle.js:869)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (datatables.bundle.js:15123)
    at comp.ngOnInit (comp.ts:149)
    at callHook (core.js:3892)
```

I've searched for it on the web but couldn't find an answer to solve my issue. As I told before, this suddenly became an issue without me changing something about the DataTable..

Thanks in advance people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because there was an error that was occuring inside the `comp.getColumns()` which held the `dataTable` from being initialized.